# HTML/CSS: pseudo-class selector not behaving expectedly

Tags: html, css, anchor, selector, pseudo-class

The following code should exhibit intended functionality:

```
    <head>
        <style>
        a:active
        {
            color:teal;
        }
        a:hover
        {
            color:green;
...  
...  
...  

    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.co.uk">Googs!</a>
...
```

[See entire code here](http://jsfiddle.net/popstack/SNwRQ/)

Comment: I do not see the issue here.  http://jsfiddle.net/jfeltis/8GVNp/1/

Comment: What do you expect to see? What do you see?

Comment: @Joe Well, you did switch the rules `:P`

Comment: What's in those `...` parts? Did you close your `a:hover` rule?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas That's true.  Maybe that is the key!  :D

Comment: @Joe I suspect the OP wants the `:active` rule to override the `:hover` rule once the mouse button is pressed. Switching the rules does seem to do that.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas So it does.  I'll post that as the answer, then.

Comment: Come on, put the code directly in your question. It's not like it's that much longer than what you already have here. If you can edit to put in a link, you can edit it to paste the full code.

Comment: Guys, see the full code at http://jsfiddle.net/popstack/SNwRQ/ and maybe then find issue with this

Comment: @popstack The order of your rules is not right. First link, then hover, then active.

Comment: @MrLister, I wanted to demonstrate/test all associated functions of <a> and a:

Comment: You can always write out all combinations in full... `a:active:hover`, `a:visited:active:hover` etc etc.

Comment: @MrLister, again, any particular sequence it should follow...?

Comment: No, it's not a sequence. The problem is that, for instance, `a:hover` and `a:visited` have exactly the same specificity - one does not override the other. So whatever you put in last in your CSS is the rule in effect. That's all. However, `a:visited:hover` is more specific than either `a:visited` or `a:hover`, so it doesn't matter where you put that.

Comment: I repeat (to all), pointers to specific past questions/resource/documented-examples will always be appreciated!

Comment: @MrLister While that is true - CSS does operate on a point system for precedence - the OP's example is a matter of order.  Because the CSS selectors are pointing to the same element + a pseudo-class, the first rule is overridden.

Comment: @Joe That's why I said "whatever you put in last in your CSS is the rule in effect. That's all."

Comment: @popstack This is the formal specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

Comment: @MrLister Valid.  +1 for the w3 spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your CSS rules.

```
...
a:hover{color: #000;}
a:active{color: #c0c0c0;}
...
```

Comment: Okay, the correct sequence followed is link, hover, active ( and visited).
Why so?
Pointers to any documentations...?

Comment: @popstack Here is a decent article on how CSS precedence works.  http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

It looks good and I assume the ellipsis represents the closing bracket.  Are you overriding the cascade deeper down the page in another style?  Also, I prefer to make sure to detail the style tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

Comment: Browsers have always used `"text/css"` for a default type, even before HTML5 formally established this, so it was never really necessary. Otherwise, you couldn't have had inline style attributes!

Comment: Sorry.  My bad. Still rather new to the forum. It looks like you're sorted. Good luck.